# How to remove flash cache on a web site periodically

Tags: html, xml, flash, caching

I'm using a flash rotating banner in my website which takes images and descriptions from an XML file.

I do changes to my XML very often... but in my local machine, the banner takes a day or two to get updated.

Although I can clear my local machine's cache, the problem still remains for other users who visit my web page..

is there a programmatic way in flash or in html to overcome this problem ? Maybe a server configuration? Please help me with this..

*PS: below code works fine, but it clears out the cache completely...
i need to clear XMl cache after a specific time period.. please help.*

```
var timestamp:Date = new Date(); 
xmlData.load("/flash/images.xml?cachebuster=" + timestamp.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clear the cache every day, use this:

```
var timestamp:Date = new Date(); 
xmlData.load("/flash/images.xml?cachebuster=" + timestamp.getMonth() + timestamp.getDate());
```

Comment: I've added this code in the first frame.. i don't think its working correctly because I havent used stop(); 

should I use a stop() at the beginning of the code or ur code will do the trick itself? 

And, thnx a lot Sam :D

Comment: Please ignore the previous comment.. u saved my day. it works perfectly.thank you loads. Cheers !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you desperately need the XML to update continuously (like live-statistics) you can call the code each time your banner loops before populating your content.

In general, Sam's code is fine - often you don't need your flash to clear the XML after a time period - it only needs to clear each time the user views your banner.